# cursor wont return a row no matter what

Tags: java, android, cursor

i'm trying to get the latest row that I have inserted into the DB, into the cursor. 
I have tried many types of the query, and nothing seem to work.

, here is my code:

```
public Expense createExpense(Expense expense) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ExpDataBase.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, expense.getDesc());
    values.put(ExpDataBase.COLUMN_amount, expense.getAmount());
    values.put(ExpDataBase.COLUMN_DATE, expense.getDate().toString());
    values.put(ExpDataBase.COLUMN_category, expense.getCategory());

    Integer insertId =(int) database.insert(ExpDataBase.TABLE_NAME, null,
            values);    

    String id="'"+insertId.toString()+"'";

    Cursor c = database.query(ExpDataBase.TABLE_NAME, null,
            null, null, null, null, null);
int i=  c.getCount();


    Cursor cursor= database.query(ExpDataBase.TABLE_NAME, null,ExpDataBase.COLUMN_ID+"="+id, null, null, null, null);
```

*the insert method works, i have seen the row in the DB table.
*the getCount returns the same number as the insertId

but when i try to get the last row into the cursor, i get nothing, i see in the cursor that it returned -1 in the number of rows.

im lost. please help me :(

Comment: What String value is `ExpDataBase.COLUMN_ID`?

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken you have your problem on the query

```
String[] fields = new String[]{ExpDataBase.COLUMN_ID};
Cursor cursor= database.query(ExpDataBase.TABLE_NAME, fields,ExpDataBase.COLUMN_ID+"="+id, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: @PavelKrivosheev Are you sure that the id from "String id="'"+insertId.toString()+"'";" is the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

```
public Expense createExpense(Expense expense) {
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(ExpDataBase.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, expense.getDesc());
values.put(ExpDataBase.COLUMN_amount, expense.getAmount());
values.put(ExpDataBase.COLUMN_DATE, expense.getDate().toString());
values.put(ExpDataBase.COLUMN_category, expense.getCategory());

long insertId = database.insert(ExpDataBase.TABLE_NAME, null,
        values);    

String id="'"+insertId.toString()+"'";

Cursor c = database.query(ExpDataBase.TABLE_NAME, null,
        null, null, null, null, null);
int i=  c.getCount();


Cursor cursor= database.query(ExpDataBase.TABLE_NAME, null,ExpDataBase.COLUMN_ID+"=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(insertId)}, null, null, null);
```